# Use global script with nextjs

Tags: next.js

Im converting a old react application to nextjs and need to include a script that is global:
In the old application we just included the scipts in the header and then added this in the top of the file and used it: `/* global liquidDonutChart */`

We will re-work this in the future but right now I just need it to work.

```
import { GET } from '@/utils/api';
import { LiquidChart } from './LiquidChart';
import Script from 'next/script';

export async function Temperature() {
    const tempInfo = await GET('api/getTemp');
    const { ChartData, AvailableCategories } = tempInfo;
    const chart = await JSON.parse(ChartData);

    return (
        <div className="flex h-[200px] w-[168px] flex-col items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-wt-white p-2">
            <div className="flex h-[148px] w-[148px] items-center justify-center rounded-[50%] bg-wt-smoke">
                <LiquidChart {...{ chart }} />
            </div>
            <Script src="liquidDonutChart.min.js" strategy="lazyOnload" />
            <Script src="d3.min.js" strategy="lazyOnload" />
        </div>
    );
}
```

--

```
'use client';

// @ts-expect-error
export function LiquidChart({ chart }) {
    const liquidDonutOptions = {
        showBG: false,
        animate: true,
        biggerLiquidDonut: false,
        noHoverOnChartBars: true,
        disableTooltip: true,
        arcWidthBase: null,
        arcWidthHover: null,
    };
    if (chart) liquidDonutChart('#liquid-gauge', chart, liquidDonutOptions);
    return <div id="liquid-gauge" style={{ width: '145px', height: '145px' }} className="dashboard-chart" />;
}
```

But the liquidDonutChart ofc get "is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

It was easier than I first thought:

Working code:

```
<>
        <div id="liquid-gauge" style={{ width: '145px', height: '145px' }} className="dashboard-chart" />
        <Script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js" />
        <Script src="scripts/d3.min.js" strategy="afterInteractive" />
        <Script
            src="scripts/liquidDonutChart.min.js"
            strategy="afterInteractive"
            onLoad={() => {
                // @ts-expect-error
                liquidDonutChart('#liquid-gauge', chart, liquidDonutOptions);
            }}
        />
    </>
```